# do a fold without Photoshop

Tags: css, fold

I'm trying to make a fold using only CSS, so far this is what I have: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ka736/5/)

I'm not sure whether it looks like a fold, I think it can be done better. How can I make this look better? Is there a tutorial somewhere that addresses this issue?

ps I changed the link because I had webkit shadow only, now its good

Comment: please notice I changed the link

Comment: instead create 2 divs `#page_left` and `#page_right`. That way you can change the left page css props as you do for your right.

Comment: I will try it, but my idea of a fold is that the left side would have to look 'brighter' than the right side

Comment: You need to try. The way you have it right now, you cannot add a lighter shadow to the right side of your left sheet. And that will make it look nice.

Comment: Hmmm...I think you could be right :) Will try it